# Java cannot connect to mySQL by JPA

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, maven

i have problem with connect to database. When i use adnotations on my User class i got message from @Table(name = "users") (where users is table name in mysql) " Assign data source and there is nothing.
My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<persistence-unit name="JavaEELearning" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name = "hibernate.connection.url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/users" />
        <property name = "hibernate.connection.username" value = "root" />
        <property name = "hibernate.connection.password" value = "" />
        <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name = "hibernate.dialect" value = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value = "update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>JavaEELearn</groupId>
<artifactId>JavaEE</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>


<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
```

Also when im started my tomcat server then throw exception

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence

Normally when i conect by hibernate.cfg.xml is working.

Comment: `jdbc:mysql://localhost/users` may be you should put ports also like `localhost:3306` or IP

Comment: Do you deploy the jar with that class correctly? Plain  Tomcat Doesn’t provide it.

Comment: Resolve. My Idea ignored my deploy in tomcat and that was reason. Thank you :)